# How to make it so that the property is ignored if it has a string type?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have a model:

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

I want the property 'Order' to be ignored if the response contains that property of type string and not ignore if object. Maybe, JsonIgnoreAtribute with something options

Third-party service send json to my endpoint. First option has view:

```
{
    "data": {
        "order": "T5TKlQn-SlCJTZJuUvC05g",
        "id": "T5TKlQn-SlCJTZJuUvC05g"
   }
}
```

Second option has view:

```
{
    "data": {
        "order": {
            "id": "dhdjd",
            "name": "test"
        },
        "id": "T5TKlQn-SlCJTZJuUvC05g"
    }
}
```

And I want to ignore the order property if it has string type

This json is parameter to api:

```
[HttpPost("order")]
public async Task OrderAsync([FromBody] Data viewModel)
{
    // .. code
}
```

Comment: By "that property of type string" you mean `OrderId`? Your question is pretty unclear - the title makes it sound like you want to ignore string properties, but the body of your question makes it sound like you want to ignore *other* properties if there's a string property...

Comment: Your second option is invalid JSON. Did you mean the penultimate brace to be a closing brace?

Comment: (Fundamentally, I'd be surprised if you could do this easily without a custom converter.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, second option is object

Comment: I'm not talking about the object for `order`. I'm talking about the brace after the value for `id`...

Comment: I've now fixed up the broken quote as well... it would really help if you could take some time to make sure you post *valid* JSON in future.

Comment: Have both of your option in an Json array, paste it to https://app.quicktype.io. It will generate the converter for both. Change the convert to skip the token when it's string. and remove the string property. voila. Adding "[,]" and a copy past and done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO it is better to use Newtonsoft.Json because code is much more simple and clear. TextJson will need a custom json converter

```
var json1=@"{
    ""data"": {
        ""order"": ""T5TKlQn-SlCJTZJuUvC05g"",
        ""id"": ""T5TKlQn-SlCJTZJuUvC05g""
   }
}";

var json2=@"{
    ""data"": {
        ""order"": {
            ""id"": ""dhdjd"",
            ""name"": ""test""
        },
        ""id"": ""T5TKlQn-SlCJTZJuUvC05g""
    }
}";

using Newtonsoft.Json;

Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json1).data;
```

classes

```
public class Root
{
    public Data data {get;set;}
}
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public string OrderId { get; set; }

    public Order Order { get; set; }
    
    public Data(JToken order)
    {
        if(order.Type==JTokenType.Object)
        Order=order.ToObject<Order>();
    }

    public Data() {}
}
public class Order
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

or if you still want to use text.json it will be more complicated

```
using System.Text.Json;

var jsonObj = System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonNode.Parse(json1);

if ( jsonObj.AsObject()["data"]["order"].GetType().ToString()
           != "System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonObject") 
                    jsonObj.AsObject()["data"]["order"]=null;

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
};

var data=jsonObj.Deserialize<Root>(options).data;
```

api

```
[HttpPost("order")]
public async Task OrderAsync([FromBody]JsonNode jsonObj)
{
    if (jsonObj.AsObject()["data"]["order"].GetType().ToString()
           != "System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonObject")
                jsonObj.AsObject()["data"]["order"] = null;

            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
            };

             Data data = jsonObj.Deserialize<Root>(options).data;

    // .. code
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I get error: "Each parameter in the deserialization constructor on type 'Data' must bind to an object property or field on deserialization. Each parameter name must match with a property or field on the object. The match can be case-insensitive."

Comment: @ViktorBylbas You have  put using Newtonsoft.Json; at the top of your code

Comment: I added this using. But I get this error

Comment: @ViktorBylbas I am sorry, but all my code is tested and works properly. I even created 2 variants for you - one for Text.Json another Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps the problem is due to the fact that this json comes in as a parameter in the api

Comment: @ViktorBylbas you should start from this,if it is a controller action input parameter.  I am just wondering how you tested my code? Where did you get json? You should be honest or you are waisting our time.  You have to post the code how you are getting this json

Comment: I edit my question. This json get from third-party service in my endpoints. Maybe I do different models with order string and object. Thanks for you time

Comment: @ViktorBylbas And now you will have to post API startup or program file where a controller is configured